# How to write a measure that counts rows from 2 different date columns in Power BI within a given date period?

Tags: date, excel-formula, powerbi, dax, measure

I need to create a measure that counts rows based on 2 different date columns where the dates are in that date period month.
Using 10/1/2023 as an reference example this should return 4 records.
Where the Work Date is <= 10/1/2023 and the Paid Date is >= 10/1/2023
If I used 11/1/2023 it should return 5 records.

In Excel formula would look something like this:

```
=IFERROR(
COUNTIFS(
NapkingForkSales!$AX:$AX,"<="&Summary!I$7
,NapkingForkSales!$BA:$BA,">="&Summary!I$7
),0)
```

In Excel this is easily accomplished by adding a filter and then entering "Custom Date" for both Date columns.

Test Data :

[image]

Date Filters in Excel :

[image]

For example in excel the custom filter options: Work Date is before or equal to 10/1/2023 and Paid Date is after or equal to 10/1/2023

Adding a Custom Filter Excel :

[image]

The data model is using both active and inactive relationships.
How would I translate this to DAX?

| OrderDate | OrderEndMonth | Forks | Napkins | Work Date | Paid Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/13/2023 | 2/1/2023 | 1 | 0 |  |  |
| 2/23/2023 | 2/1/2023 | 1 | 0 |  |  |
| 3/2/2023 | 3/1/2023 | 1 | 0 | 3/1/2023 | 12/6/2023 |
| 10/22/2019 | 10/1/2019 | 1 | 0 | 10/1/2019 | 11/26/2023 |
| 10/29/2019 | 10/1/2019 | 1 | 0 |  |  |
| 12/23/2019 | 12/1/2019 | 1 | 0 | 12/1/2019 | 10/22/2020 |
| 4/4/2023 | 4/1/2023 | 1 | 0 |  |  |
| 4/18/2023 | 4/1/2023 | 1 | 5 | 4/1/2023 | 6/22/2023 |
| 3/26/2019 | 3/1/2019 | 1 | 3 | 4/1/2019 | 8/30/2019 |
| 4/30/2019 | 4/1/2019 | 1 | 0 |  |  |
| 5/28/2019 | 5/1/2019 | 1 | 0 |  |  |
| 6/4/2019 | 6/1/2019 | 1 | 1 | 6/1/2019 | 7/15/2023 |
| 10/31/2023 | 10/1/2023 | 1 | 1 | 11/1/2023 | 12/14/2023 |
| 7/9/2019 | 7/1/2019 | 1 | 4 | 7/1/2019 | 8/21/2019 |
| 7/31/2018 | 7/1/2018 | 1 | 2 | 8/1/2018 | 10/10/2018 |
| 3/13/2018 | 3/1/2018 | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| 7/23/2019 | 7/1/2019 | 1 | 0 | 8/1/2019 | 9/24/2019 |
| 10/24/2019 | 10/1/2019 | 1 | 0 | 11/1/2019 | 12/11/2023 |
| 10/17/2019 | 10/1/2019 | 1 | 0 |  |  |
| 11/25/2019 | 11/1/2019 | 1 | 0 |  |  |
| 12/3/2019 | 12/1/2019 | 1 | 1 | 12/1/2019 | 11/15/2023 |
| 1/7/2020 | 1/1/2020 | 1 | 7 | 2/1/2020 | 2/28/2020 |
| 1/2/2020 | 1/1/2020 | 1 | 2 | 1/1/2020 | 2/18/2020 |

Using 10/1/2023 as an reference example this should return 4 records.
Where the Work Date is <= 10/1/2023 and the Paid Date is >= 10/1/2023
If I used 11/1/2023 it should return 5 records.

Expected Values:

| Dates | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | 4 |
| 2/1/2023 | 4 |
| 3/1/2023 | 5 |
| 4/1/2023 | 6 |
| 5/1/2023 | 6 |
| 6/1/2023 | 6 |
| 7/1/2023 | 5 |
| 8/1/2023 | 4 |
| 9/1/2023 | 4 |
| 10/1/2023 | 4 |
| 11/1/2023 | 5 |
| 12/1/2022 | 3 |

Here are some of the measures I tried but was unsuccessful. The closest one to any real result was TestD but even that was terribly inaccurate.

Adding the PBIX here [Sample Test Dates.PBIX](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/4tb6b55fe48jp537hfhlu/SampleTestDates.pbix?rlkey=4r0v7pndazus5fl77ewymjr95&dl=0)

```
TestA = CALCULATE(

        SUMX (
            'Date',
            CALCULATE (
                COUNTROWS ( 'TestData' ),
                FILTER (
                    'TestData',
                    [Date] <= 'TestData'[WorkDate]
                        && [Date] <= 'TestData'[PaidDate]
                )
            )
        )
)

TestB = CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(
                    FILTER('TestData', 'TestData'[WorkDate] <= MAX('Date'[Date])
                    )
                )
)

TestC = CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('TestData')
    ,'TestData'[WorkDate] <= MAX('Date'[Date]) && 'TestData'[PaidDate] >= MAX('Date'[Date])
)

TestD = CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
    ALL('TestData'),
    'TestData'[WorkDate] <= MAX('Date'[Date])
    &&
    'TestData'[PaidDate] >= MAX('Date'[Date])
    )
    )
)

TestG = COUNTROWS(
FILTER(
'TestData',
'TestData'[Work Date] >= MIN('Date'[Date]) // date1 must be in the current month 1/2
&& 'TestData'[Work Date]<= MAX('Date'[Date]) // date1 must be in the current month 2/2
&& 'TestData'[Paid Date] >= MIN('Date'[Date]) // date 2 must be in the current month 1/2
&& 'TestData'[Paid Date] <= MAX('Date'[Date] // date2 must be in the current month 2/2

)))
```

Comment: Your test D is close to your objectif, but you need to add "&& >= Min(calendar[date) " in order to make it work. Else your row will be counted everymonth until the max date is reached

Comment: The closest I have come is Test D but the values for June (5) should be 6 and October (5) should be 5. Still working through this but seems as if this should be much simpler than what its turning out to be. 
TestD = CALCULATE(
 COUNTROWS(
     FILTER(
     ALL('TestData'),
     'TestData'[Work Date] <= MAX('Date'[Date])
        &&
     'TestData'[Paid Date] >= MAX('Date'[Date])
     )
 )
)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that your column must be highter than the min(calendar[date]) AND smaller than the max(calendar[date]).

I used this dax code in a similar situation, where I needed to countrows everymonth using multiple date column :

```
COUNTROWS(
FILTER(
Table-name,
[date1] >= MIN(Calendar[date]) // date1 must be in the current month 1/2
&& [date1] <= MAX(Calendar[date] // date1 must be in the current month 2/2
&& [date2] >= MIN(Calendar[date]) // date 2 must be in the current month 1/2
&& [date2] <= MAX(Calendar[date] // date2 must be in the current month 2/2

))
```

Second way of counting rows here, add a new column in your table, who can check wether your 2 dates are in the same month :

```
check column = 
IF (
MONTH([date1]) = MONTH ([date2]),1,0)
```

Your new measure :

```
Measure = 
CALCULATE (
COUNTROWS (Table), check column = 1)
```

I cannot test it right now, let me know what it says !

Comment: For the second way, that doesn't come out right as there is only 1 matching column.
For the first solution, it only shows yearly totals and nothing else, and even those are incorrect. 
I will add the expected values to this post.
Ill keep trying things out and follow up if I find anything. Appreciate the help kindly.

Comment: Added the drpbox link to the pbix [SampleTestDates.PBIX](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/4tb6b55fe48jp537hfhlu/SampleTestDates.pbix?rlkey=4r0v7pndazus5fl77ewymjr95&dl=0)

Comment: What is happening is that this is first filtering the table on the Work Date and then

It filters that filtered table by the paid date. The problem is that I cant get that to work in a measure.

Heres what I tried.

 

DatesB =

VAR xTable =

CALCULATETABLE(

        'TestData', 'TestData'[Work Date] <= MAX('Date'[Date])

        && ISBLANK('TestData'[Work Date]) = FALSE()

)

 

VAR xCount = CALCULATE(

    COUNTROWS(xTable)

    ,FILTER(xTable, 'TestData'[Paid Date] >= MAX('Date'[Date]) )

)

 

RETURN xCount